# How do I import local modules stored in my Google Drive to Google Collab?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I did connect Google Collab with my Google Drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

and I can already see my local Google Drive folders and files

```
pwd
>> /content

ls drive/MyDrive/
>> MyFolder
```

But now, how can I import local modules I have installed within `/MyFolder/SubFolder/Source`? Will I have to mark all the directories in-between as python modules adding `__init__.py` to all of them?

Currently, my notebook is located within `/MyFolder`, so I can easily import my modules with

```
from SubFolder.source.mypersonalmodule import *
```

*ALTERNATIVELY*

Is there a way to run my notebook from `content/drive/MyDrive/MyFolder/`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify where your file is starting from `drive.MyDrive`.

For example, if I had a file `test_function.py` in the root of my Google Drive with the function `square` in it, I can import it by

```
from drive.MyDrive.test_function import square
```

Example image of execution and printing of paths:

[image: Colab notebook example]

And yes, you are able to run your Jupyter Notebooks from anywhere in your Google Drive. Just find the file, click on it, and click on "Open with Google Colaboratory" at the top when Google says there is "No preview available".

Comment: Thanks! I am running my Jupyter Notebook from within the drive e.g. `drive/MyDrive/Folder/NotebookHere`. But apparently, it runs from `/content` or at least that's what it returns when I run `!pwd`

Comment: Google's Colab notebooks should be smart enough to figure out the paths based on my answer. The script import statement with `from ... import ...` should still work because you're referencing the relative path from `content/`. So just point your import to where your module file. It doesn't look like you need to have `__init__.py` files in all of them (at least if you only have one file with all your functions).

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't need `__init__.py` in `MyDrive\, but it does require for any subfolder after/within `MyDrive\`.